# Error in strsplit(unitspec, “ ”) in code for Machine Learning for Hackers

Tags: r

I am new to this book and get an error with the example code for the first chapter. I installed the latest version of R 3.4.0 and RStudio. I installed package_install.R given by the sample code and then installed ggplot2 by myself. When I run the code ufo_sightings.R, I got an error as follow

```
> quick.hist <- ggplot(ufo.us, aes(x = DateOccurred)) +
+   geom_histogram() + 
+   scale_x_date(breaks =date_breaks("50 years"),labels = date_format("%Y"))
> ggsave(plot = quick.hist,
+        filename = file.path("images", "quick_hist.pdf"),
+        height = 6,
+        width = 8)
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).
```

Comment: The code you included in your question doesn't actually show an error (warnings are just that, warnings of something that *might* be wrong). Where does the error in your question title actually occur?

Comment: It just shows the warning and can not plot.

Answer (score 0):

The default binwidth for geom_histogram is 30. To make the warning go away (and probably improve the readability of your chart), try different values for binwidth or set it to 30 and move on without a warning.

```
quick.hist <- ggplot(ufo.us, aes(x = DateOccurred)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 30) + 
    scale_x_date(breaks =date_breaks("50 years"),labels = date_format("%Y"))
```

Comment: I do like what you said but there is a new warning > quick.hist <- ggplot(ufo.us, aes(x = DateOccurred)) +
+   geom_histogram(binwidth = 30) + 
+   scale_x_date(breaks =date_breaks("50 years"),labels = date_format("%Y"))
> ggsave(plot = quick.hist,
+        filename = file.path("images", "quick_hist.pdf"),
+        height = 6,
+        width = 8)
Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).